# Как вывести в цикле 2 sql запроса?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть 2 sql запроса.

1. Первый запрос выводит рандомно записи у которого **wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'prop_featured'**

   ```sql
   SELECT
     wp_term_relationships.object_id
   FROM
     `wp_term_relationships`
     LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (
       wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_postmeta.post_id
     )
   WHERE
     `term_taxonomy_id` = 88 AND
     wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'prop_featured'
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 3;
   ```
2. Второй запрос тоже выводит рандомно записи у которого **wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'prop_featured' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = 1**

   ```sql
   SELECT
     *
   FROM
     `wp_term_relationships`
     LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (
       wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_postmeta.post_id
     )
   WHERE
     `term_taxonomy_id` = 88 AND
     wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'prop_featured' AND
     wp_postmeta.meta_value = 1
   ORDER BY RAND()
   LIMIT 2;
   ```

Как правильно их объединить, чтобы в итоге получилось так. 2 и 5 значение было из второго sql запроса, а 1,3,4 из первого sql запроса.

1. значение из 1 запроса
2. значение из 2 запроса
3. значение из 1 запроса
4. значение из 1 запроса
5. значение из 2 запроса

Попытался сделать в цикле для 2 и 5 итерации, не вышло, а когда стал читать все пишут, чтоб так не делать.

Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запросы отличаются селектом, выборкой и лимитом, остальное одно и тоже. Значит заводите нужные переменные и подставляете эти переменные в запрос.

Comment: @DaemonHK имеете ввиду, если в цикле итерация равна 2, то в зависимости от этого подставленная переменная меняет значение в запросе. Верно?

Comment: Да, верно. Вы попробуйте и покажите, что получилось)

Comment: @DaemonHK чтот не особо выходит(((

https://ibb.co/GJb4Ghm

Comment: Зачем там счетчики? Покажите последовательность/условия выполнения того или иного запроса

Comment: @DaemonHK а как я пойму, какая итерация идёт без счётчика?

Comment: Понял. А почему вы условия вынесли перед циклом? Они внутри должны быть

Comment: @DaemonHK чтот я уже запутался. Вы про условие внутри if? Если я его в цикл внесу, то как эти условия повлияются на запрос за циклом?

Comment: $sqlQuery должен быть после цикла, в котором вы определите переменные для него